# ValueError - Feeding an array of images into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm adapting [this tutorial here](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/02_Convolutional_Neural_Network.ipynb) so I can train a ConvNet in my own set of images.

So I made this function to try and get batches, though it does not create batches (yet):

```
def training_batch(batch_size):
  images = trainpaths

  for i in range(len(images)):
    # converting the path to an image
    image = mpimg.imread(images[i])
    images[i] = image

  # Create batches
  X, Y = images, trainlabels

  return X, Y
```

And this function is called here:

```
def optimize(num_iterations):
  global total_iterations

  for i in range(total_iterations,
               total_iterations + num_iterations):

    # Get a batch of training examples.
    # x_batch now holds a batch of images and
    # y_true_batch are the true labels for those images.

    x_batch, y_true_batch = training_batch(train_batch_size)

    # Put the batch into a dict with the proper names
    # for placeholder variables in the TensorFlow graph.
    feed_dict_train = {x: x_batch,
                       y_true: y_true_batch}

    # Run the optimizer using this batch of training data.
    # TensorFlow assigns the variables in feed_dict_train
    # to the placeholder variables and then runs the optimizer.
    session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)

    (...)
```

thing is if I run this if I run this code I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scr.py", line 405, in <module>
    optimize(1)
  File "scr.py", line 379, in optimize session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 905, in run run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1116, in _run str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2034, 218, 178, 3) for Tensor u'x:0', which has shape '(?, 116412)'
```

Can someone shine some light on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following line:

```
x_batch = x_batch.reshape((-1, 218 * 178 * 3))
```

should fix the error. However, since you're building a convolutional neural network, you'll need spatial information of the images anyway. So I'd suggest you change your `x` placeholder to shape `(None, 218, 178, 3)`, rather than `(None, 116412)` instead. The `x_batch` conversion in this case will not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you need to reshape the input to `(?, 116412)`

```
def optimize(num_iterations):
  global total_iterations

  for i in range(total_iterations,
               total_iterations + num_iterations):

    # Get a batch of training examples.
    # x_batch now holds a batch of images and
    # y_true_batch are the true labels for those images.

    x_batch, y_true_batch = training_batch(train_batch_size)
    x_batch = tf.reshape(x_batch,[-1, 218 * 178 * 3])
    # Put the batch into a dict with the proper names
    # for placeholder variables in the TensorFlow graph.
    feed_dict_train = {x: x_batch,
                       y_true: y_true_batch}

    # Run the optimizer using this batch of training data.
    # TensorFlow assigns the variables in feed_dict_train
    # to the placeholder variables and then runs the optimizer.
    session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)

    (...)
```